# Randint is not working and i have no idea why

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

```
import turtle#importer turtle pour pouvoir l'utiliser
import random
from random import random #importer random pour pouvoir laisser le choix à l'ordinateur. Le choix sera aléatoire.
 #pour pouvoir utiliser screen turtle, demanderdes questions à l'utilisateur
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
#from random import random 

window = Screen()

bgcolor = None

while bgcolor is None:
    bgcolor = window.textinput("Choose a background color between black, red or yellow", "Color")
window.bgcolor(bgcolor)

color = None
while color is None:
    color=window.textinput("quelle couleur voulez vous que les bords soit?","couleur:")
    turtle.pencolor(color)

z=window.textinput("nommez votre fichier(vous ne pouvez qu'utiliser des lettres",'name:')
window.title(z)

turtle.setup(width=0.8, height=0.8)#agrandit le screen
turtle.screensize(10000,10000)#pour que l'utilisateur puisse scrooll

turtle.screensize(canvwidth=400, canvheight=400)

#x=int(window.textinput("choisissez les coordonnées où commencer.","x:"))
#y=int(window.textinput("choisissez les coordonnées où commencer.","y:"))
s=window.textinput("choisissez l'épaisseur de l'étoilee","epaisseur")
nb=int(window.textinput("combien d'étoile","nb:"))
p=0

turtle.pensize(s)
turtle.hideturtle()           #make the turtle invisible
turtle.penup()                #don't draw when turtle moves
turtle.goto(0,0)              #move the turtle to a location xy
turtle.showturtle()           #make the turtle visible
turtle.pendown()              #prepare to draw
turtle.pencolor(color)        #Set pen color = user selected foreground color
turtle.screensize(10000,10000)

#turtle.pencolor(bgcolor)
while p<nb:
    turtle.right(60)
    for sides in range(6):
        turtle.color(random(), random(), random()) #rbg
        turtle.pencolor(color)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.forward(50)

        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(120)
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.right(180)
        turtle.end_fill()
        turtle.forward(50)
        
    turtle.up()
    turtle.right(random.randint(1,360))#met que ce soit un random chiffre ici
    turtle.forward(random.randint(100,400))#randint
    turtle.down()
             
    p+=1
```

is there a problem in the way i coded this? My problem is that after this, when i try to use randint like so:

turtle.forward(random.randint(100,400))

it gives me this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ritamansour/Desktop/tyfkgjhv.py", line 62, in 
turtle.right(random.randint(1,360))#met que ce soit un random chiffre ici
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'

I dont understand where the problem is, because randint is apart of import random. If you need to see the full code, let me know. Thank you.

Comment: i realised it doesnt look right so here is the full code

Comment: You should always post the code so it's easier for the community to help you out...

Comment: `from random import random` you reassigned the variable "random" to the function, not the module. Once you've done this you can't do `random.randint` because its not the module any more.

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module you bind the module object to some name in your module's namespace.

```
import random
```

binds the `random` module to "random".

```
from random import random
```

takes the "random" function object in the random module and rebinds it to your "random" variable. This discards the reference you created with `import random` and now you can't use "random" to refer to the module any more.

The solution is to remove `from random import random` and then wherever you are calling `random()` to get a random number, do `random.random()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Too much code =).  But thanks for including enough context!

The problem is that you import random as a module.

```
import random  # "random" is the module
```

Then the very next line you import the function random from that module, which has the same name.

```
from random import random  # "random" is now random.random
```

So your random function will work, but

```
random()  # .XXXXX
```

this clobbers your module, you can't access functions from it with `random.foobar`, because it is a function.

```
random.foobar()  # AttributeError, function random.random doesn't have .foobar
```

It is typically bad practice to import both ways, just do one of

```
import random
 ...
random.random()
random.randint()
```

or

```
from random import random, randint
random()
randint()
```

Comment: Speaking of enough context, how does this solve the problem?

Comment: I dont really understand what i should modify for randint to work. Could you elaborate please?Thank you. (i dont understand what the last two lines are for)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing random from random which imports the function just import it once as a library.

```
import random

print(random.randint(1,360))
```

So what you would want is this

```
turtle.right(random.randint(1,360))
turtle.forward(random.randint(100,400))
```

And then earlier on to make different calls the random function this way

```
turtle.color(random.random(), random.random(), random.random())
```

Answer (score 0):

You import random but you bind random with random like (from random import random)
This is wrong way to do that......

You can only import random

OR

You can use (from random import*)

You can do both...